# How to make groovysh enter interactive mode after executing scripts?

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

Python has an option to enter interactive mode after executing scripts:

```
$ python -i util.py
>>>
```

I found this article [groovy equivalent to "python -i "?](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/groovy-equivalent-to-quot-python-i-lt-script-py-gt-quot-td372587.html) but nothing seems to work for groovysh 2.3.0. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need to execute this with one command only? If not, try executing groovysh first:

```
$ groovysh
```

then in groovysh:

```
groovy:000> :load your_script.groovy
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like in groovy 2.3.0 commands need to start with `:`.